# Lauterbach Trace 32 debugger shows Illegal sap id code error

Tags: trace32, lauterbach

Whenever I am trying to run any script on Trace32 I am getting below error.
How can I fix this? Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

I want to run few .cmm scripts

Comment: Please add information about processor architecture, processor name and the command that caused the error.

Comment: LS1046ARDB BOARD ,Armv8,
It is throwing error at this command "Data.IN EDBG:0x40000000 "

Comment: I'd suggest to contact Lauterbach Support and include all information and scripts. https://support.lauterbach.com/